# Trying to get rid of commas in numbers with regex in R gives strange output

Tags: regex, r

I'm new to R. This is my data (using dplyr):

```
> withCommas   
Source: local data frame [326 x 1]

             NA
1   16,244,600 
2    8,227,103 
3    5,959,718 
4    3,428,131 
5    2,612,878 
6    2,471,784 
7    2,252,664 
8    2,014,775 
9    2,014,670 
10   1,841,710 
..          ... 

Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  326 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ : Factor w/ 207 levels ""," 1,008 "," 1,129 ",..: 40 178 143 100 66 63 61 58 57 16 ...
```

I'm trying to get rid of the commas (so the first row should be 16244600). So I tried the following:

```
#1st try
noCommas <- gsub("([0-9]+)\\,([0-9])", "\\1\\2", withCommas)
#2nd try
noCommas <- gsub(",", "", withCommas)
```

In all cases, I got this output:

```
[1] "c(40 178 143 100 66 63 61 58 57 16 14 11 9 6 4 182 176 174 170 161 148 147 139 137 136 134 118 117 116 114 113 109 107 105 95 93 92 90 89 88 87 84 83 78 75 74 73 72 71 70 56 55 49 47 43 42 39 28 25 24 23 190 188 181 172 165 163 162 160 153 152 151 150 149 146 145 144 138 132 131 130 129 128 127 126 125 124 115 112 111 110 106 98 97 96 94 86 85 82 81 80 77 76 69 68 54 52 51 50 46 45 44 41 \n38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 27 26 22 21 20 19 18 17 187 186 185 184 183 179 177 169 168 167 166 159 158 157 156 155 142 141 140 122 121 120 119 104 103 102 101 99 67 65 64 62 60 59 15 13 12 10 8 7 5 3 2 189 180 175 173 173 171 164 154 135 133 108 91 79 53 48 123 1 191 191 191 191 191 1 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 1 206 1 205 200 202 198 201 196 \n195 204 194 199 193 203 197 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)"
```

This seems very strange to me as I don't understand where the numbers are coming from. Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** 
Only the first 225 rows of the variable withCommas have values. After that, the values of the column are empty.

Source: http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/GDP-ranking-table

CSV: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv

Comment: is this `withCommas` a column name?

Comment: `gsub(",", "", withCommas)` should work. Are you sure you didn't change `withCommas` before trying that? Also remember that removing the commas won't make them numbers - you'll also have to use `as.numeric`.

Comment: your variable seems to be a factor. You need to turn it to a character variable before the gsub :  `noCommas <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+)\\,([0-9])", "\\1\\2", as.character(withCommas)))`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: withCommas is the whole var.

Comment: @scoa: I receive "Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion" The value of noCommas is "NA".

Comment: how did you import the data from the csv file?

Comment: Subset the column and it should be happy. `noCommas = as.numeric(gsub(",",  "", as.character(withCommas[, 1])))`

Comment: @scoa: read.csv("getdata-data-GDP.csv"). The desired column was saved to withCommas with select() from dplyr.

Comment: @AkhilNair: you might be interested in the selected solution below. I tried your solution but it gave me:
"Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> noCommas2
[1] NA"

Comment: @AmirRahbaran Strange, it works find for me, when using the same method of reading in the data you are. Only one `NA` being returned hints towards a data frame being passed to the function instead of the column (because then it would try and run the function on a single string which evaluates to the column, resulting in an NA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution? I think that main problems arise because a data frame is a list and `gsub` is expecting a character string and so passing it to that function cause to apply the function to the lists and not the elements that are part of the lists themselves. That's the reason for an `apply` function. Or of course, if the columns is one, passing just that column as a vector with `ddf$column_with_commas` as the solution provided by other users.

```
 as.data.frame(apply(ddf, 2, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))))
        NA.
1  16244600
2   8227103
3   5959718
4   3428131
5   2612878
6   2471784
7   2252664
8   2014775
9   2014670
10  1841710
```

#### Data

```
ddf <- structure(list(NA. = structure(c(2L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1,841,710", "16,244,600", "2,014,670", 
"2,014,775", "2,252,664", "2,471,784", "2,612,878", "3,428,131", 
"5,959,718", "8,227,103"), class = "factor")), .Names = "NA.", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thanks :) This was the only solution that worked. Thanks to everyone. I wonder why my data frame structure (withCommas) became so complicated. I created my data frame by selecting the necessary column with the select() function from dplyr and saving the result to a new variable (i.e., to withCommas).

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- read.table(header=F, text="1   16,244,600 
2    8,227,103 
3    5,959,718 
4    3,428,131 
5    2,612,878 
6    2,471,784 
7    2,252,664 
8    2,014,775 
9    2,014,670 
10   1,841,710 ")
colnames(data) <- c("a","b")
data$b <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data$b))
```

Output:

```
    a        b
1   1 16244600
2   2  8227103
3   3  5959718
4   4  3428131
5   5  2612878
6   6  2471784
7   7  2252664
8   8  2014775
9   9  2014670
10 10  1841710
```

Comment: `,` is not a regex special character so you don't need to escape it or use `fixed = TRUE`. This is not different from what the OP tried (which should have worked, he probably did something wrong).

Comment: @Molx Thank you. I have edited the answer and removed that argument.